# How to use variable in JDBC Object? Jmeter

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jmeter

I have a JMeter job that is performing some UI tests on a webpage, it should then store the text value of an object in a variable called "impid"

```
var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()        
var importID = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath('html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[6]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/strong')).getText() 
vars.put('impid','importID')
```

I believe that part is working, I then want the pass the value of that variable into a mysql JDBC Request, like so -

```
select id, fileName, timeEntered, timeStarted, timeCompleted, comments from netdespatch.fileImportStore where id = ${impid};
```

But the varialbe is just being used as the "name" it is not being converted into the variable value..

I'm sure someone know what i'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe that part is working

how do you know? Given your XPath syntax I don't believe it matches anything.

Your select query looks good so I would recommend double checking your `${impid}` variable using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

You can also try printing the variable value into *jmeter.log* file right from the WebDriver Sampler like:

```
WDS.log.info('importID value == ' + importID)
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: Yeah that is working, your WDS.log.info prints the value I expected it to, so at least I know that is working, thank you for that..

Comment: But I still can't seem to pass the variable to the sql request, I will update the question to include how I have set it up, but it still not passing...

Answer (score 0):

```
String s ="select id, fileName, timeEntered, timeStarted, timeCompleted, comments from netdespatch.fileImportStore where id = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(s);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, impid);
```

Use place holder '?' and then bind with sentInt (or adequate method for other types)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it looks like it would work, but I don't understand what to do with this?

Comment: That's if you want to add own classes. If you are just using the Gui then see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html#adding_requests and look into the example with the Prepared Select Statement.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the issue, the variable I was passing between Webdriver and JDBC needed to be a jmeter UDV..so

I have a UDV called impID

grabbed my value from webdriver and put it in the impID variable

```
var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
var importID = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath('html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[6]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/strong')).getText() 
vars.put('impID',importID)
```

this puts the value of importID into the UDV impID

Then on the JDBC request, use a "Prepared Select Statement"

```
select id, fileName, timeEntered, timeStarted, timeCompleted from nd.fileImportStore where id = ?
```

and in Parameter Value enter = ${impID}

And that worked :)